# Nested loops not working properly in parallal

Tags: javascript, jquery, themoviedb-api

I am a student and I am trying to build a movie web site based on the movie database API. The problem with my code is that the nested loops are not working. The outer loop always finish first jumping directly to the nth value while the inner loop executes fine.

```
function getMovieslist() {
  //////////////////////action movies/////////////////
  for(j=1;j<2;j++){
    let list = '';
    axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=API_KEY&with_genres=28&page='+j)
      .then((response) => {
        let movies = response.data.results;
        console.log(response);
        console.log(j);
        let indexx=0;
        $.each(movies, (index, movie) =>{
            list+=`
                <div style="z-index=0;" class=" swiper-slide"><img style="z-index=0;" onclick="movieSelected('${movies[indexx].id}')" 
                src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movies[indexx].poster_path}" 
                height="auto" width="150" class="img-thumbnail"></div>
            `;
            indexx++;
        })
        $('#movie-list-action').html(list);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

I want to get the movie list from more than one page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that outer loop, but it's only ever going to iterate once with those conditions.

Comment: Do you realise your outer loop is running only once, i.e. for the value of j=1?
You might want to try a while loop incrementing page number inside the loop and until your api request is returning results.

Comment: i tried many values but value of j always jumps to the ending value of j